# Visual Studio Nuget - How to use package without any documentation?

Tags: visual-studio-2012

I'm not sure if I'm just being stupid but if I create a VS project for a Windows mobile phone, I can add packages to the project, stuff like JSON parsers etc.

I added SteamSharp which is a library that works with mobile that has some interaction with the Steam network. It's installed fine although I can't see it in references, not sure if I'm meant to...

My question is, how on earth do I even use it? The guy who's written it has provided no documentation at all... Is there some magic VS tool that lets me see the functions it provides or something? It just seems stupid to create a library without any documentation?!

Comment: Also here's the project URL for SteamSharp package: https://github.com/ShaneC/SteamSharp

Answer (score 0):

You can look inside the `SteamSharp.Test` folder to see how they use their own library code. You need to add a `using SteamSharp;` statement at the beginning of your file to import the namespace. Then IntelliSense can help you.